# Can PHP introspect or detect tag's current indent level within source document?

Tags: php, introspection, pragma, indentation

For those of us still inlining PHP within an HTML structure, is there a way to introspect the indent level (within the source) of the current PHP statement/tag being evaluated?

Consider the following block:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <?php insert_nav_menu() ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    function insert_nav_menu(){
        $current_indent_level = {get current indent level of tag in source};
        $indent = ( $current_indent_level ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $current_indent_level ) : '';

        echo "{$indent}<p>Insert nav menu here...</p>\n";
    }
?>
```

Is there any known pragma or introspection method that will reveal anything about the line that the function call was made on so that the HTML generated by the PHP function, when viewed in the browser's source will show consistent indenting?

Comment: You can use an HTML-tidy processor after PHP has emitted the HTML... Doing things that way has the added advantage of allowing you to minify the HTML after you're done debugging it, just by throwing a switch.

Comment: @Borealid - an interesting approach that I had never considered. Can you expand a little? I have no experience with post-processing PHP-generated HTML.

Comment: this is usually done via something like the Smarty template engine, but that's not mandatory. You first enable output buffering, then you apply the tidier (PHP has an HTML Tidy extension built in) before flushing the buffer to the user. It could theoretically be done streaming with limited look-ahead as well.

Comment: Did you ever happen to figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

As @Borealid mentioned, I'd look at post-processing using PHP: Tidy -- http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

To let you know, PHP knows nothing of HTML.
As well as of SQL.  Or JS.
To PHP, it's only strings with no particular meaning.
It's programmer's job, not program's.

If you want to know an indent level, you have to count it.

And post-processing, of which everyone is talking about here, won't help you.